# Connect Macbook Pro to HDTV with audio

Tags: mac, hdmi, macbook-pro, mini-displayport

I have a Macbook Pro (from fall of 2009), which has a Mini DisplayPort.  I want to be able to connect this to my HDTV through HDMI and get video and audio going through the TV.  What is the cheapest and easiest way to go about doing this (this can involve more than one cable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dr.Bott's [Mini DisplayPort to HDMI Adapter Pro w/Optical Audio](http://www.drbott.net/product/9601-MDOP/) works with 2009 vintage MB Pros.

Comment: There's got to be a way to do it without spending $100.

Comment: @James: When I was looking for the same thing, I remember looking at DisplayPort > HDMI cables that had a USB soundcard attached, which you used instead of the soundcard in the laptop. They are much cheaper. I just went with sound from the headphone socket in the end.

Comment: Check out Monoprice.com. They may have a cheaper alternative.

Comment: This looks to do the same thing, or am I reading it wrong? http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10428&cs_id=1042802&p_id=6331&seq=1&format=2

Comment: Pretty sure that's it! You may want to browse reviews there first it first just to make sure it will do what you need....